# How to configure proxy settings "syntax error *extra junk at end of file"

Tags: apt

I got the following error after configuring proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf as Acquire::http::proxy `http://192.168.96.0:8080`:

```
e: syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: extra junk at end of file.
```

and I don't have the proxy authentication. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please post the contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forget `;` at the end of line.

Try this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy http://192.168.96.0:808;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that after removing the "http://" after the proxy in the above string has helped.

So the revised line would be:
`Acquire::http::proxy 192.168.96.0:80;`

Answer (score 1):

you much change to 
Acquire::http::proxy "192.168.96.0:80"; 
The ";" must place end of the line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and had to put the address and port part in quotation marks. Likes so:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "192.168.96.0:80;"
```