# How to solve a syntax error while updating?

Tags: updates, synaptic

I keep getting the next message when I try to update or install a package:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:229: Extra junk at end of file
```

I can't use synaptic or the download manager or the terminal. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Please add into the question the lines shown when you do a `tail /etc/apt/apt.conf` (there seems to be something invalid in this file). Btw this file does not exist on my machine :P I do have a directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104047/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-on-ubuntu-server-11-0

Comment: #### UNetbootin (Source) - http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FC91AE7E
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu lucid main

#### Wine (Source) - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/
## Run this command:  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9CB8DB0
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu lucid main 

I am using Lucid 10.04 Thanks

Comment: In [this question](http://superuser.com/q/457214) a user have the same problem. He solve editing the file, but didn't tell exactly what was wrong. @RickPorter Please, upload the content of the file in paste.ubuntu.com and link it in your question.

Comment: The error is saying the junk is at line 229 of /etc/apt/apt.conf

Could you paste your whole /etc/apt/apt.conf file into pastebin or some such for us?

Comment: @RickPorter please add this INTO your question and not as a comment.