# how to solve E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file

Tags: apt

This error is showing up when using `sudo apt get update`:

`E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file`

[image: error message from terminal]

Comment: Your command is wrong. The correct one is `sudo apt-get update`, or `sudo apt update`. run the correct command and check if the problem is still present.

Comment: If the problem persists, edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf`: you can fix the error only if you check the file content (as the error suggests to you)

Comment: this is the content of the file `apt.conf`

Acquire::http::proxy “http://<proxy_server>:<port>/”;

Comment: @AnmolChooudhary please add the output of `cat -A /etc/apt/apt.conf` to your question using the [edit] button

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you wrote that the content of the file is:

```
Acquire::http::proxy “http://<proxy_server>:<port>/”;
```

In this case, the content of your `apt.conf` is not well-formed.
If you need it to use `apt` behind a proxy, `<proxy_server>` and `<port>` should be replaced by the real values of proxy server and port.

Just as an example, you can check [the question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/104047/1037999) to see how a proper `apt.conf` file is written.

Therefore, you have two possible solutions:

1. Make a backup of the file by `sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.bak`, then check if `sudo apt-get update` works (this may work only if you don't really need to be behind a proxy).
2. Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and edit the file replacing the two placeholders with correct proxy server and port.