# E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-no-recommendsc:3: Extra junk at end of file

Tags: updates

sudo aptupdate then find this (E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-no-recommendsc:3: Extra junk at end of file) error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411884/how-to-solve-e-syntax-error-etc-apt-apt-conf2-extra-junk-at-end-of-file)